why calibration adc and dac is important in stm32f4?
I am using STM32F4 to perform sensing on my circuit. Before doing so, I would like to calibrate it first. I am doing this because I read that calibration is 'important,' but I don't understand why calibration 'must' be done. I say this because I previously used the ADC and DAC directly without calibration, and it worked fine. Therefore, I want to clarify why calibration must be done. Is it possible to proceed without it?
I am using STM32F4, and when I use "HAL_ADCEx_Calibration_Start(&hadc1, ADC_SINGLE_ENDED);" it doesn't work and throws an error. I have run out of ideas for calibration besides the above method. Is it true that STM32F4 does not have calibration, or is there information that I missed? Please help.

Elaborate on why you "cannot use" that function. Elaborate on what "an error" consisted of. Help others to help you.

Questions should focus on one problem at the time — asking thing like "I also want to ask why calibration is important, and what happens if calibration is not performed?", will lead to opinionated answers, making your question off-topic. Please revise.

"But it resulted in an error" - Please [edit] the question and add in the full error (as text) inside of it

I have edited it, sorry for the confusion earlier. @Damien_The_Unbeliever

I have edited it, sorry for the confusion earlier. @DarkBee

It depends how accurately you want your ADC or DAC to provide answers in volts. If you really care about that then you should really calibrate against some known stable external reference voltage to improve accuracy. Many ADC chips have an internal bandgap reference that can serve the same purpose for self calibration. Without calibration you may have a (usually) small DC offset error and an incorrect slope on the calibration line. These are artefacts of real chips that can be calibrated out.

when i read the RM, i found a idea, What I understand is that I set limits for the calculation results, which are called 'thresholds.' Is this correct? I am a beginner, and the language in the RM is still too difficult for me to understand, so I need your help.

Looking at the HAL ADC Extended module for stm32f4xx it doesn't look like a function by the name of HAL_ADCEx_Calibration_Start exists. The 'calibration' that you typically do for an ADC is setting the appropriate resolution, sample rate, reference voltages and operation mode to fully capture the data you're looking for.
It also seems like the ADC can only read values between its positive and negative reference values (page 395 of the reference guide). Using the same voltages as you input to the potentiometer should be fine.

I have read about AWD that you mentioned in the RM (Reference Manual). What I understand is that I set limits for the calculation results, which are called 'thresholds.' Is this correct? I am a beginner, and the language in the RM is still too difficult for me to understand, so I need your help. Please respond, can i ask you to provide a simple example for the program?
